# Craft CLI RC1 Connectivity Issues with MAMP Pro

Tags: craft3, installation, mysql, cli

I've been trying to run the new Craft CLI for the last couple of versions without any success. I figured maybe since we weren't at RC1 yet that it wasn't fully working. After seeing Ryan's video about it at https://mijingo.com/lessons/craft-3-command-line/ I realized that wasn't the case (and with RC1 being released today).

I am using MAMP Pro (like Ryan does in his video), but I have it using the standard MySQL port at 3306. I also have PHP 7.1 installed at the terminal through homebrew and pdo_mysql is a compiled in module. I am also using RC1.

Interestingly, if I use localhost I get a completely different message than if I use 127.0.0.1. But regardless, both still fail.

```
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [localhost] localhost
Database port: [3306] 3306
Database username: [root] root
Database password:
Database name: craft3
Database table prefix:
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [localhost] 127.0.0.1
Database port: [3306] 3306
Database username: [root] root
Database password:
Database name: [craft3] craft3
Database table prefix:
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

If I create the database manually and put the credentials into my .env file everything connects just fine without any issue. Is there something else I should be considering?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After playing with this a little further it seems the unixSocket setting is necessary to get this working so I added:

```
'unixSocket' => getenv('DB_SOCKET')
```

To `config/db.php` and then added:

```
DB_SOCKET="/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

To my `.env` file. After that, the installation will go through using the CLI. Perhaps there's still an option that doesn't require the unixSocket be set?

Comment: I've been running into this problem using MAMP Pro and MySQL and this answer worked for me. When I use a separately set up Postgres database the additions are not needed (perhaps obviously).

Comment: This solution didn't fix the problem for me as the file in `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` just did not exist!

But, a simple solution was instead of using `localhost` when running `craft setup` in terminal, I used `127.0.0.1` and it all ran smoothly

Comment: As well as turning on the setting Andrew Hahn posted below.

Answer (score 16):

I gave everything a try, but the only thing that worked for me was ensuring "Allow network access to MySQL" was ticked in MAMP.

Screenshot: http://c42.co/Ur30EJ[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. This resolved a lot of issues I've been having with using env files. 

Comment: Thanks Andrew! that setting tip helped me fix it. Also worth noting! I couldn't get past the setup with a blank password, I had to use "root" as the password to get it to work.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: This works and I like the answer better since it doesn't require configuring a socket for every environment. MAMP is causing the issue so MAMP is what you fix.

Comment: This was all I needed to do, thanks!

Comment: same here, installation of craftcms goes thru now

Answer (score 3):

Jason Mayo's strategy of changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in .env file worked for me as well  (MAMP Pro v6 on Mac OS 11.4 Big Sur)

Comment: This seems to be the answer that works after upgrading from MAMP 5 -> 6