# Craft 3 Command setup failing

Tags: craft3, installation, composer

I've installed Craft 3 through composer and I'm attempting to work through the setup process within terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ jamie$ ~/Documents/repos/__craft-3-beta/craft setup
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [localhost] 
Database port: [3306] 
Database username: [root] 
Database password: 
Database name: craft-three
Database table prefix: 
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [localhost] 127.0.0.1
Database port: [3306] 
Database username: [root] 
Database password: 
Database name: [craft-three] 
Database table prefix: 
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Notice that I get 2 different errors when using the IP add and localhost for DB_SERVER

I also cant get it working when manually filling in the .env file.

I'm using MAMP Pro on a Mac.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you use root for your db password? I had issues here as had changed it in the past, so used a new user/pw

Comment: I've tried 'root' and leaving it blank. Both result in the same errors. 

I dont really want to change my root password, as i'll have to change all instances of the password within phpMyAdmin, and other scripts which are used with MAMP

Comment: Don't have MAMP install locally, but doesn't it use a different database port by default?

Answer (score 5):

I was just confronted with this too. You most likely need to specify the unixSocket attribute for the MAMP Pro database. Take a look at my problem and solution at [Craft CLI RC1 Connectivity Issues with MAMP Pro](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23056/craft-cli-rc1-connectivity-issues-with-mamp-pro). Though if you're not able to get it working at all even manually I would definitely suggest resetting your root password in MAMP Pro as well.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked mentioned here.

But after these steps

1. Enable "Allow network access to MySQL" -> "only from this Mac"
2. Save
3. Restart

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Had very similar issues but no MAMP or WAMP; just vanilla Apache and MySQL 5.7.23 (Had the same error with 8.0.12 too - did not test the solution).

It worked for me to type in 127.0.0.1 instead of *blank* or *localhost* in the terminal window when going through the Craft3 setup steps.

```
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [localhost] 127.0.0.1
Database port: [3306] 
Database username: [root] 
Database password: 
Database name: craft_test_h828
Database table prefix: 
Testing database credentials... success!
Saving database credentials to your .env file... done
```

Answer (score 1):

This note is a "thank you" to the commentators above. After a few hours of "slugging" (starting with the effort to download composer), here is what worked for me:

```
Which database driver ... : mysql
Database server name or IP ... : 127.0.0.1
Database port: [3306] 8889 (note: via MAMP)
Database username: [root] root
Database password:
Database name: EnergyAudit
Database table prefix (type "none" for none): Probs
Testing database credentials ... success!
Saving database credentials to your .env file ... done
```