# How do I get past this MySQL error installing Craft 3 using CLI

Tags: install, mysql, composer, cli

I am using https://box.scotch.io/ (vagrant).

I'm trying to install Craft 3 with the cli, but can't get past these errors:

- Connection refused
- No such file or directory

One or the other error shows up depending on what I use for the host name.

- I have tried the answer [here.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23056/craft-cli-rc1-connectivity-issues-with-mamp-pro)
- I can connect fine with Sequel Pro using the same credentials.

(Note: I did intentionally change the db name and password from the defaults that came with Scotchbox, and have successfully connected with those new details using Sequel Pro).

See log:

```
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [192.168.33.10] 
Database port: [3306] 
Database username: [root] 
Database password: 
Database name: [craft] 
Database table prefix: 
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [192.168.33.10] localhost
Database port: [3306] 
Database username: [root] 
Database password: 
Database name: [craft] 
Database table prefix: 
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [localhost] 127.0.0.1
Database port: [3306] 
Database username: [root] 
Database password: 
Database name: [craft] 
Database table prefix: 
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all very specific to the box you're using, and how it's configured. I realize Scotch Box is a historically popular setup; you might also consider [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) as it is geared specifically for PHP development.

Anyway, according to the [Scotch Box docs](https://box.scotch.io/docs/) the setup should be:

Database Host: localhost
Database User: root
Database Password: root

Which I assume you're doing in the second example? You are also running all of this from *inside* of the box, yes?

Answer (score 1):

The default database name created by Scotchbox is `scotchbox`, not Craft, and the DB Password is `root`.

You can find the DB connection details in [the Scotchbox Docs](https://box.scotch.io/docs/).

Comment: The database name should be the name of the database. If he chose the name `craft` it is craft. If he created a database with the name `foo` it will be that. The same goes for the password as well. You can set/change it. These values are not "hard-coded"

Comment: @RobinSchambach If the OP provisioned a Scotchbox, which he _clearly says he did_, then the database is created with the name Scotchbox with username password root:root by default, as stated in the Scotchbox docs… https://box.scotch.io/docs/

Comment: But he could have created a new one. You could have asked him if that's the case or if he didn't -so you could hint about the docs and the default values but it sounded like it's impossible to create a db called `craft`

Comment: Thanks for the downvote though @RobinSchambach.

Comment: He doesn't say he created a new DB, he does say he used Scotchbox, so I told him the connection parameters he needs to connect to _a Scotchbox provisioned database_ which is what he asked. Sigh.

Comment: "I can connect fine with Sequel Pro using the same credentials." I expect he is aware of the database name if he was in the interface and checked the credentials

Comment: Sorry folks - to clarify, I did intentionally change the db name and password from the defaults that came with Scotchbox, and have successfully connected with those new details using SP.

Answer (score 1):

Fully detailed video on how to install Craft with Scotchbox is here:

https://craftquest.io/courses/localhosting-craft-cms/4312

Missing step is SSHing into vagrant box